# Warning in origRenderFunc() :

Tags: r, graph, shiny, widget, plotly

Using plot_ly, I received this following warning message:

```
Warning in origRenderFunc() :Ignoring explicitly provided widget ID "2e241c7bce6b"; Shiny doesn't use them
```

Because of this warning message, my graph does not appear. My question is about how to fix ghis warning message. The user upload an excel file. After uploading the file, the user can plot it (I used plotly because it's very cool). The user can choose what can a graph we would like to see. He has 2 choices: line or scatterplot.

Below the function with the 3 choices of graph

```
plotType <- function(z, type){
    switch(type,
     "Line" = plot_ly(z, 
                      type = "scatter",
                      mode ="lines"),
     "Scatterplot" = plot_ly(z,
                          type = "scatter",
                          mode = "markers")
              )
  }
```

My ui code. The user upload his/her file and then select the variables he/she would like to see.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarPanel(
 fileInput(inputId = "file1", label = "Choose CSV File",
          multiple = FALSE,
          accept = c("text/csv",
                     "text/comma-separated-values, text/plain",
                     ".csv")
),
selectInput('xcol', 'X Variable', ""),
selectInput('ycol', 'Y Variable', "", selected = ""),
radioButtons(inputId ="graph", label = "Type of graph:",
             list("Line", "Scatterplot"),
             selected = "Line")
mainPanel(
tabsetPanel( type = "tabs",
             tabPanel(
               # App title
               titlePanel("Uploading Files"),
               # Output: Data file
               tableOutput("contents")
             ),
             tabPanel(
               titlePanel("Plot"),
               plotOutput('MyPlot'))
))))
```

My serve code

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
data <- reactive({
req(input$file1) # require that the input is available

df <- read.csv(input$file1$datapath,
               header = input$header,
               sep = input$sep,
               quote = input$quote)

updateSelectInput(session, inputId = 'xcol', label = 'X Variable',
                  choices = names(df), selected = names(df)[sapply(df, is.numeric)])
updateSelectInput(session, inputId = 'ycol', label = 'Y Variable',
                  choices = names(df), selected = names(df)[sapply(df, is.numeric)])

return(df)
})
output$MyPlot <- renderPlotly({
  x <- data()[, c(input$xcol, input$ycol)]
  plotType(x, input$graph)

})}
```

Comment: Are you able to plot this outside the shiny application?

Comment: I did not try it.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik, I tried outside and it doesn't work. I tried with plot, and it works! But I don't still understand why using the potly in inside and outside the shiny application, it does not work!

Comment: Please make a reproducible example.

Comment: `plotType <- function(data, a, b, style){
  if(style == "s"){
            plot_ly(data, 
                     x = a,
                     y = b,
                     type = "scatter",
                     mode ="markers")
  } else{
    if(style == "l"){
    plot_ly(data, 
            x = a,
            y = b,
            type = "scatter",
            mode = "line")
    } else {
    print("scatterplot or a line")
  }
}}
plotType(mtcars, a = ~mpg, b = ~drat, style = "s")`

Comment: Please see a [quick tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) on how to use this site.